# MSN Explorer Premium without MSN Account

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, msn

I have a bug on my site which only appears in MSN Explorer. The user agent indicates that it could be using IE7 rendering however, the bug cannot be replicated with IE7. So it must obviously be something to do with MSN Explorer. It's a simple javascript submit form call which shouldn't cause any problems.

I was wondering if anyone has an tips on testing MSN Explorer Premium without the need of an MSN account? At the moment you must have purchased MSN to use the browser, which makes it very hard to test in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: as of the post of this question, it's not possible to use MSN explorer without having an MSN paid account. But, it does work off the version of IE installed much like AOL does.